# Godot: Position2D node not sending proper location

Tags: godot

I am new to Godot and am currently making a roguelike game. It's in the very beginning stages, but I am stuck on one specific part. I have a system set up so that when you click on a certain space, the player will move to the position 2D node associated with that space. However, whenever I actually try it out, after clicking in the area the player moves to what appears to be a set area instead of where I want.

With this problem, I have no real idea how to fix it or what to search for on the internet because I am new to Godot and game development. I was hoping someone could answer my question directly here.

Comment: You are not showing us what you tried. I have no way to tell you what you need to fix. I can, at best speculate: my guess is that you are using the wrong coordinates space.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.